# Apply a transformation to SVG element coordinates to get new coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, coordinates

I'm working with an SVG viewer based in D3.js, which is used to place markers on maps. Here is a simplified example of the resulting markup after placing a marker on the map (excluding outer SVG and G tags wrapped around the map & makers for zooming & panning in D3):

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 612 792">
    <g>
       <!-- All the map geometry in here; excluded for brevity -->
    </g>
    <g id="markers">
       <!-- Markers appended here -->
       <g class="marker" transform="translate(158.75, 77)">
          <path class="marker-symbol" d="M0,0.65C-1.4722431864335457,-0.8666666666666667,1.4722431864335457,-0.8666666666666667,0,0.65Z" fill="red"></path>
       </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have a requirement to be able to switch out the SVG file used as the "basemap" that markers are placed on, meaning that the coordinates of the markers need to be updated.

I went through an exercise of calculating a new transform property that could be applied to the group of markers using the old SVG dimensions and new SVG dimensions as such:

```
//OLD SVG
old_minX = 1.5 
old_minY = 126.1 
old_maxX = 611.9 
old_maxY = 665.8 
old_width = old_maxX - old_minX
old_height = old_maxY - old_minY

//NEW SVG
new_minX = 91.757199686237271    
new_minY = -519.48732490973259   
new_maxX = 734.05396114497432 
new_maxY = 115.11440116896759 
new_width = new_maxX - new_minX 
new_height = new_maxY - new_minY

scale_x = new_width / old_width
scale_y = new_height/ old_height
translate-x = new_minX – (old_minX * scale_x) 
translate-y = new_minY – (old_minY * scale_y)
```

**Which gave me:**
translate(90.1788164258, -667.760954072) scale(1.05225550698, 1.17584162698)

I then took this transform and applied it to the `g.marker` surrounding the existing markers mapped onto the new SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="91.7571996862373 -519.487324909733 642.296761458737 634.6017260787">
    <g>
       <!-- All the map geometry in here; excluded for brevity -->
    </g>
    <g id="markers" transform="translate(90.1788164258, -667.760954072) scale(1.05225550698, 1.17584162698)">
       <!-- Markers appended here -->
       <g class="marker" transform="translate(158.75, 77)">
          <path class="marker-symbol" d="M0,0.65C-1.4722431864335457,-0.8666666666666667,1.4722431864335457,-0.8666666666666667,0,0.65Z" fill="red"></path>
       </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This *seems* to get the existing markers to show where they should be, but I don't think this approach is ideal. If I wanted to add a new marker to that group, I wouldn't be able to pass it simple coordinates from where the user clicked on the map.

What I think needs to happen is to transform the existing `g.marker` translate(x,y) values to new values based on the parent `g.markers` translate, but I don't know how to achieve this. How should I approach this?

Comment: "a requirement to be able to switch out the SVG file used as the "basemap" that markers are placed on" - do all the svg basemaps share the same geographic projection?